# ORA-00936: missing expression when using pyodbc to extract specific data from a SQL server

Tags: python, sql, oracle, syntax, pyodbc

Unable to understand why my sql query is throwing an exception of [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00936: missing expression.

The case is that the code seems to be working fine when I'm using 
select* from reports.ORDERS_NOW.
So it's letting me pull all the data, but for my case, I want only specific columns for which I'm writing the query. Please look at the code below and let me know what's wrong with it.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

conn = conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=abcd;UID=xxxxxx;PWD=xxxxxx')

if conn:
    print("Connection is successful")
```

## db query

```
sql = '''

select [QUANTITY] from reports.ORDERS_NOW

'''

df = pd.read_sql(sql,conn)
```

Answer (score 1):

i  think [] is not allowed in oracle so remove it

```
select QUANTITY from reports.ORDERS_NOW
```